# How to add multiple sound buttons in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a simple funny sound app for my friends with their favorite meme sounds. This obviously means I have to add multiple buttons and set them to play sounds. I used this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oj4f8721LM) to make a button that plays a fart noise. I planned on making a new java class and using the same code but changing it so it fits the new noise and adding a new button. I did everything I did when I added the first button, but for some reason, the second button does not work. I've tried looking at other StackOverflow questions and tutorials but none seem to work. Here is my MainActivity.java class code:

```
    package com.example.app;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            final MediaPlayer FartSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fartsound);

            Button playfart = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playfart);

            playfart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FartSoundMP.start();

                }


            });





            }
```

Here is my SecondActivity.java class code:

```
    package com.example.app;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;

    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            final MediaPlayer cryMp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cry);

            Button playcry =  (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playcry);

            playcry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    cryMp.start();

                }


            });





        }}
```

Here is my XML layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Below are Cool Noises!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.262" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playfart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"


            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="264dp"
            android:text="Fart"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playcry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"


            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
            android:text="Cry"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my strings.xml file :

```
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">App</string>

        <string name="playfart"> Fart</string>
        <string name="playcry"> Cry </string>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, you only have to create another activity if you want to move to another screen (that usually have another layout). It seems that this is not what you want because you only have one layout. You should do something like this:

```
 package com.example.app;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            final MediaPlayer FartSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fartsound);
            final MediaPlayer cryMp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cry);

            Button playfart = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playfart);
            Button playcry =  (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playcry);

            playfart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FartSoundMP.start();

                }


            });


            playcry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    cryMp.start();

                }


            });


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create `SecondActivity`:

```java
    package com.example.app;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            final MediaPlayer FartSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fartsound);

            Button playfart = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playfart);

            playfart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FartSoundMP.start();

                }

             });

            final MediaPlayer cryMp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cry);

            Button playcry =  (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.playcry);

            playcry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    cryMp.start();

                }


            });


            }

     }
```